# My database connection in swift is not working

Tags: swift, database

I am trying to get data out of my Localhost database. I am running MAMP on my Mac and have built a Web Server. I have made a php script and when I access it with my browser it returns data. The problem occurs in my Swift code that should take the data from the URL Session and parse it.  In the downloadItems() function below the data and error variables are returning nil values, but the response variable returns data that indicates the connection is working.  I expect the data variable to have data that my php is getting out of my database.

```
import Foundation

protocol FeedModelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}

class FeedModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {       
    weak var delegate: FeedModelProtocol!        
    let urlPath = "http://x*//MyWebService/api/Get_Data2.php" //Change to the web address of your stock_service.php file

    func downloadItems() {            
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }else {
                print("stocks downloaded")
                print(error!)
                print(data!)
                print(response!)
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }               
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {            
        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)                
        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let stocks = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count {                
            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary                
            let stock = StockModel()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let name = jsonElement["name"] as? String,
                let price = jsonElement["price"] as? String {
                print(name)
                print(price)
                stock.name = name
                stock.price = price
            }                
            stocks.add(stock)                
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in                
            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: stocks)                
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use the class?  Show us the code of that as well.  Please clarify *"My php is working..."* and *"It is not returning any data"*.  What PHP?  None here.  Lastly add in the tags the language this is in.  It's not PHP, what is it?

Comment: Not returning data: Clarify: What's your print? `"Error"` or `"stocks downloaded"`? If it's `"Error"`, please `print("Error: \(error)")` instead, read the error. If it's `"stocks downloaded"`, it means that you parser has an issue. But we can't guess which one with absence of info.